# How to receive PostgreSQL LISTEN/NOTIFY with Apache Camel?

Tags: postgresql, apache-camel, notify, listen

I have a PostgreSQL database that fires a `NOTIFY mychannel` when rows in a table are inserted.

I would like to send this info out to a variety of sources (Twitter, etc) using Apache Camel.

I understand that one can use JDBC and call `LISTEN mychannel` to receive those notifications, but may need to use polling.

I'm pretty new to Camel, so not sure where to start. Is this something I would do with the SQL, JDBC, or Polling Consumer connectors?

Is there a built-in method to do this in Camel efficiently?

Comment: The client can only receive a notification when it actively retrieves something from the server. So you need to poll the server for notifications.

Comment: The underlying interface in PgJDBC is discussed in [the PgJDBC documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/listennotify.html). You need the raw JDBC `java.sql.Connection`, then cast it to `PGConnection` and call `getNotifications()`. If Camel has its own support, it will go via that interface in the JDBC driver, so look for `getNotifications` in the Camel sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating this question with a more recent answer. This camel component has been created:

http://camel.apache.org/pgevent.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [pgjdbc-ng](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) driver. It supports async notifications without polling.

[Write a Camel Component](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html) to use it. See the Guava Eventbus Component [source code](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-guava-eventbus/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/guava/eventbus) for inspiration.